# What motivates multivariate distributions?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-variable

Given some probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$ where $\Omega$ is some set, $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ and $P:\Omega \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is a probability function, we can define a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ in order construct distribution function $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$. I understand that this is an usefull thing as it might be difficult to analyze $P: \Omega \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ as $\Omega$ can be an arbitrary set, while we understand functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a lot better.

But what are the reasons we consider multivariate distributions - or equivalently random variable vectors $\vec X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n) : \Omega \to \mathbb R^n$?

What things do they let us or what do they simplify in contrast to univariate distributions / variables $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two random variables $X,Y$ are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)), then their joint distribution can be defined in terms of univariate distributions:

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)\;f_Y(y)
$$

If they are not, then their joint distribution is something else, so you need a multivariate distribution to describe their joint probability. Since almost every real-life statistical problem is about more then one random variable, you need multivariate distributions.